# Laravel Multiple Form Request Validation

Tags: php, forms, laravel, httprequest, laravel-5.1

I have products and software and movie belongs to product. I have created two validation requests and want to validate them like shown below.

```
public function store(StoreProductRequest $old_request)
{
    if ($old_request->type == 'MOVIE')
        $request = new StoreMovieRequest;
    else
        $request = new StoreSoftwareRequest;

    $request = $old_request;
    $request->validate();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Laravel 5.1? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: could you elaborate more by showing your tables? and what your result should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing what you want to achieve is

```
public function store(StoreProductRequest $old_request){
    if ($old_request->type == 'MOVIE'){
    $request = new Requests\StoreMovieRequest;
    $this->validate($old_request, $request->rules());
    //validation passed for StoreMovieRequest
    }
    else {
    $request = new Requests\StoreSoftwareRequest;
    $this->validate($old_request, $request->rules());
    //validation passed for StoreSoftwareRequest
    }
}
```